# get call stack for Model Classes in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

In Django, I would like to get call stacks of classes in Model; on call, and log them. The Django Model uses *QuerySet API* to access objects of the Model class.

Say, we have defined Model `class Abc`, and it is called by other django apps using *QuerySet API*.

For example -

```
Abc.objects.filter()

Abc.objects.get()
```

,etc.

I would like to add a traceback whenever that particular Model `class Abc` is called via *QuerySetAPI* .

Is traceback a correct approach here? Should I use something else?

I am using Python 2.7, Vegrant, Django 1.4.20 on Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, this is my solution. Any call to queryset api prints caller stack.

```
import inspect
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Manager

class LogManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        print inspect.stack()  # in py3.4 the [2] element was the actual caller outside Manager so I used [2:]
        return super(LogManager, self).get_queryset()

class Abc(models.Model):
    objects = LogManager()
```

UPD.: For all django versions < 1.5 you should override `get_query_set`:

```
class LogManager(Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        print inspect.stack()
        return super(LogManager, self).get_query_set()
```

Comment: Are `Class LogManager`, and `Class Abc` in the same `Model.py` file?
If so, would this work even if I have different multiple objects of different classes ?

Comment: @malhar Now they are in one `models.py` file. Do you want to use this `LogManager` with different models? It will work. You can move it somewhere outside concrete `models.py` file and use it in any model you want.

Comment: I get that. All objects of `Abc` will go through `LogManager`, and then perform the queryset operations. But, strangely, I am unable to get the stack. This means that `LogManager` is not getting called. Any idea why `LogManager get_queryset` not getting called, despite doing this?

Comment: @malhar I understand now. Try to override `get_query_set` instead of mine just because you are using old django that method is called `get_query_set`. Updated answer.

Comment: bellum, the same goes for save() method, right? something like this 
`class LogManager(Manager, models.Model):
     def save(self):
         print(inspect.stack())
         return super(LogManager, self). save()
`

Comment: @malhar, you should use it in `save` method of your model or use one of the signals, i.e. `post_save`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

Comment: bellum, Can you please tell me what `objects` in `objects  = LogManager()` does? is `objects` predefined in the `Model Class`?

Comment: @malhar It's default model `Manager`. You can override it by writing this code. You should better read django documentation about this. It's here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/managers/#manager-names